# gcm from app to server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing chat app. Downstream messages go from server to cloud and then to device.
But I don't understand how to send messages from device to server. Should I send them directly by POST or through the cloud?
What is a common way to send messagess from app to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send upstream GCM message 
refer this : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream

But i suggest you to make a simple http request to your server directly.

Comment: Is there any advantage by sending message upstream to cloud? Is sending http request is the common practice?

Comment: May suggest using Firebase ? It's now a Google-owned company and the plans are very flexible. I've used it in an app of my own.